# jackson serialization views: nested object

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

The following is a snippet from a project based on Spring Boot 1.3. Json serialization is made via Jackson 2.6.3.

I have the following Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Results<Account> getAllAccounts() throws Exception {
    return service.getAllAccounts();
}
```

The returned `Results` is as follows (getters and setters removed):

```
public class APIResults<T> {
    private Collection<T> data;
}
```

The `Account` class is as follows (getters and setters removed):

```
public class Account {
    @JsonView(Views.ViewA.class)
    private Long id;

    @JsonView(Views.ViewB.class)
    private String name;

    private String innerName;
}
```

I also have the following Json Views

```
public class Views {
    public interface ViewA {}
    public interface Publisher extends ViewB {}
}
```

The motive is to return different view from the same controller, based on some predict.
So I'm using `AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice` to set the view at run-time. When setting `bodyContainer.setSerializationView(Views.ViewA.class)`, I'm getting  an empty json result and not a json array of objects that only contains the `id` property.
 I suspect this is because the `data` property in `APIResults< T >` is not annotated with `@JsonView`, however shouldn't non annotated properties be included in all views ([doc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION))?
Is there a way to get what i want without adding the `@JsonView` annotation to `APIResults< T >` (this is not an option).
I know i can use Jackson mixin to get the functionality i desire, however is there a way to do that using Json views ?

Comment: This is not clear: do you want to return different json-views from the controller method ? If no, you may freely add @JsonView to the controller method.

Comment: Yep. I want to return different views based on some predict (explicitly, based on the user authorities). updated question to reflect that

Comment: Never used this advice. Anyway, first - try add @ResponseBody to controller method, and second - check if advice is being called at all.

Comment: the advice is called, and the controller method does return a json payload (the controller class is annotated with @RestController). I suspect something is not working with the json default view inclusion config (or am i getting it wrong ?)

Comment: Jackson [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) says that views are identified by classes, not interfaces, as you mentioned. Also, in my code, I used inner `public static` classes for the purpose.

Comment: I think views interface should work (see spring integration tutorial [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)). Anyhow, changing to static inner classes does not change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, spring MVC [`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html) [has been improved](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12179) to  set jackson mapper feature `DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` to `false`, so not annotated property `data` is not serialized.

To enable the feature, use following config (XML):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                 <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
                   <property name="defaultViewInclusion" value="true"/>
                 </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

With this config, you'll have `id` and `innerName` properties serialized when using `ViewA` view:

```
{"data":[
  {"id":1,"innerName":"one"},
  {"id":2,"innerName":"two"},
  {"id":3,"innerName":"three"}
]}
```

Further, you may manage to hide `innerName` also, by adding some other view annotation to it.

Comment: 10x. Indeed this works. To make this config by code (as oppose to xml) use this snippet: `@Configuration
    public static class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
            builder.defaultViewInclusion(true);
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
        }
    }`